# Displaying User Information after Authentication in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt

I have already implemented Identity with JWT token and secured the routes using `[Authorize]` attribute. This works well. There are several tutorials on securing a route using JWT and Identity but I couldn't find any on how to let a particular user only access their own stuff after they have been authenticated.

So far, I have done this:

```cs
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("protected")]
public async Task<string> ProtectedArea()
{
    var userName = User.Identity.Name;
    var user = repository.GetUserByEmail(userName);
    //var user2 = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userName); //user2.id gives null reference error
    return User.Bio;
}
```

Here, `GetUserByEmail` is a simple method that returns the User object by querying the database(i couldn't get the `UserManager` to work here either to return the User using `FindByEmailAsync` as it would throw a null reference exception)

Here's what my `claims` looks like:

```cs
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, email),
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, user.UserName),
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId, user.Id.ToString())
};
```

So what is the standard way for identifying a user from the token and then go on to display that user's info? What I have done above seems a little hacky to me but is it the right approach? Also, do I need to perform a check on every route and get the User Id via a method or is it possible to do so via some attribute as well?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason using `UserManager` failed was because you're attempting to get the user by id (`FindByIdAsync`), but supplying the username as the "id". That will never match, so no user is returned and your variable is null. If you simply use `FindByNameAsync` instead, you'd be fine.

However, there's actually an even easier way:

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

Comment: Hi Chris, Actually I had supplied the ID there, I added that comment line here manually without pasting and made the mistake :). I just tried with GetUserAsync but still got the null reference error :(

But my main concern is regarding the displaying of custom info based on user. Should I get the user id from `User.Identity.Name` on every protected route where I want to show customized info to each user,  or is there a way to do so by using using some attribute like the `[Authorize]` (Authorize secures the routes but it doesn't help display customized based on user)?